# Facebook API Getting Friends of a friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good day, we are building an app that NEEDS to have information of user's friends' friends. For example: John logs into the app and he has 100 friends, each of those 100 friends also has 100 friends that equals to 10,000 people, application needs to get info like profile picture and basic info of those 10,000 people. We know that it was possible in the old API of Facebook, what happened now? If the current API doesn't have this function can we get exclusive access to this particular function for our servers only?

Comment: A- You need permission from EACH user you try to access their friend's list. B- It's very unlikely that Facebook would give you exclusive access.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only access (non public) data about your app's users and their friends (subject to their privacy settings)  - there's no permission which grants access to the friends of friends or their private data.

Comment: Igy, we're developing a platform that is similar to what www.thread.com was doing in 2009-2010 before they closed. Here's the source: http://techcrunch.com/2009/09/01/threadcom-raises-12-million-for-facebook-powered-matchmaking-service/  . It says:"Thread.com then uses Facebook Connect to look up some basic information about your friends and friends of your friends. It shows each match in a grid..." So back in 2009 Thread.com could pull friends of friends data. What happened today? When was this API feature disabled to pull friends of friends data and who do we write to about at Facebook?

Comment: I don't know if/when the functionality changed, but my answer is correct as regards the current API and i don't believe there's any process to apply to have the API changed to match your use-case